# Will this replacement derailleur hanger fit my bike?

Tags: compatibility, derailleur-hanger

I have a Bixs Sportivo 2 from more than 10 years ago. Derailleur hanger is broken and I lost the broken piece. I would like to buy a replacement. Can you please look at these images and tell me if it will fit.

[image: Derailleur hanger place on my bike.]

[image: Possible replacement hanger]

Comment: The shape looks close, but is it possible to put a scale on each image to verify the size?

Comment: Ideally you’d print it on a piece of paper true to size and see if it fits/matches.

Comment: I'd be concerned about the relatively sharp point at the top left "peak" of the hanger's image.  The frame itself appears round where that peak would fit, although there is the silver mark that might be where the frame was distorted from force-fitting a similar hanger.

Comment: Maybe  OK ! Try a photo without the wheel

Comment: The best thing you can do when a hanger breaks is to keep all the pieces.  I've even temporarily superglued them back together just to get a better idea of what the original looked like.   Do you still have the original hanger?

Answer (score 3):

The manufacturer of the frame will often spec the type of hanger the frame uses. The broken hanger may have a number or letters and numbers
on one side, like 207 or H23. Some makers of after market parts allow you to shop for hangers by bike brand, such as Wheels MFG - https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/manufacturers.html. If you click on your bike brand on the list this will narrow it down and give you a bit more confidence that you are going to end up with the right one.